# RewriteRule is working opposite or not working?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My default url is http://www.example.com/?page=20&id=2 and i want to show it as http://www.example.com/page/20/id/2/ with .htaccess

I use the following codes;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule page/(.*)/id/(.*)/?$ ?page=$1&id=$2 [R=301,NE,NC,L]
RewriteRule page/(.*)/?$ ?page=$1 [R=301,NE,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /

</IfModule>
```

If i remove [R=301,NE,NC,L] at the end of the codes, /page/20/id/2/ is working if i go directly but when i write as ?page=20&id=2, url is not changed on browser.

If i use as the above it redirect from /page/20/id/2/ to ?page=20&id=2 which is the opposite of what i try to do.

i will appreciate if anyone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a note, this isn't typically how people do 'nice URLs'. You are still referencing the variable names, this is fine, but not really required, so you could just have your URL as .com/20/2, but of course it's all aesthetic so it's up to you.

Comment: try changing RewriteRule `page/(.*)/id/(.*)/?$` to `RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/id/(.*)/?$` see if that helps some

Comment: /pages or /id can be change, the main issue i can't redirect the url. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: _"but when i write as ?page=20&id=2, url is not changed on browser"_ - well that’s mostly because you have done _nothing_ so far that would achieve that ... // You would only need this if there’s external links you can’t change anyway. That you change all the links your system itself outputs to the "nice" form you want in your HTML output is clear, right?

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand it won’t help, because RewriteRule checks the on _path_ component of the URL only. If you want to do anything based on the contents of the query string, you need a RewriteCond that uses the respective variable to do that.

Comment: btw what about a QSA?

Comment: I don't use any external links, all i want to change URL with user friendly views

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand both advice changed nothing. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)&id=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /page/%1/id/%2? [L,R=301]
```

htaccess fiddle http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=afb950c7-106e-5b9c-a7ed-358aed027bc0

Comment: It returns with "Page Not Found"